# Attempting to connect to Oro 4.1.1 Web API via the OAuth

Tags: orocommerce

I am trying to utilize the OroCommerce Web API which was introduced to interact with my clients.

The first step of oauth2-token seems to be working well, but he consequent requests to the api's such as customers GET, customerusers GET etc all end up with 401-Unauthorized Error.

I am trying to test the whole flow through the POSTMAN.

I have checked the Web API access is enabled and also verified that the guest users are enabled.

What's strange is the the /api/doc seems to be working well, but when I try to mimic the same via POSTMAN, it always ends up with 401 -Unauthorized Access.

Any idea why it could be failing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you included `Content-Type` and `Bearer` prefixed `Authorization` headers in the request built using POSTMAN. Like explained in [the OroCommerce documentation](https://doc.oroinc.com/api/authentication/oauth-client-credentials/).

The authentication with Bearer header also explained in [POSTMAN documentation](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#oauth-20).

Comment: I have the Authorization prefixed with Bearer Token (Bearer <accessToken>)  along with Content-Type ( application/vnd.api+json) specified. But still no avail and ends up with a 401 UnAuthorized

Comment: Is there any additional configuration or a setup required from the backend or the server